# Windows 10 JS UWP Authenticating with WCF and Active Directories

Tags: javascript, wcf, authentication, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am currently researching how to upgrade our enterprise system to a windows 10 UWP app.  We would like to target an HTML5/JS UWP.  Our current system is an ASP.NET webforms app that uses Forms authentication, the user passes types their windows credentials into our login page and the backend service validates that against Active Directories.  I need to replicate that functionality, but I am having a hard time finding information on having an HTML5/JS UWP pass a login name and password to a WCF service and storing a cookie, or token after authentication.  To be clear I cannot make this a single sign-on app, the user needs to enter their credentials each time they open the app.  Has anyone run across any good tutorials on this?

Further, once the user is validated I need to pass the token back to the WCF service so it can validate that the user making the request has security to access the resource.